# How to exclude angle brackets in regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using "expresso" to test my regular expression I have the following expression...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!£$\(\)-_+=]+
```

I have the following test cases:

```
aB8
aB_8
aB_!8
aB_!8(+=)
aB_!8(+=-_)
aB_!8(+=-_)<>
!£$%()-_+=[];:@~# \|/
!£$()-_+=[];:@~# \|/
!£$()-_+=[];:@~# \|<>/
!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>/
!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>?/
!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>.?/
!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>,.?/
!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>,.?/'
'!£$()-_+=[]{};:@~# \|<>,.?/
!£$()-_+=[]{'};:@~# \|<>,.?/
```

This case here is passing, but I want it to fail due to the angle brackets:

```
aB_!8(+=-_)<>
```

The solution will need to work for c# flavour of reg-ex. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!£$\(\)_+=-]+$
```

Add `anchors` `^$` and place `-` at the end.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/21

Comment: Thank you for your input. I don't think it is the anchors that are causing it but the subtle difference between the position of th negative sign in my example and yours. I added anchors to mine and it still did not work. Used yours and it did. Took the anchors off yours and it still worked.

Comment: @Dib yes `-` inside character range forms a range.So yours might be forming a range where `<>` would be within range.with anchors and `multiline` flag it should work

Answer (score 0):

So based upon the reply by @vks I have used

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!£$\(\)_+=-]+
```

Which is subltey different from my example

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!£$\(\)-_+=]+
```

only by the position of the NEGATIVE sign.

OR, the negative sign needs escaping!

```
\-
```